# Why does fmt lib not format std::float16_t and std::float128_t types?

Tags: c++, floating-point, number-formatting, fmt, c++23

In the following code snippet ([live](https://godbolt.org/z/h137jbfzd)), the third print statement results in a lot of error messages:

```cpp
#include <stdfloat>
#include <fmt/core.h>

int main()
{
    auto num1 { std::float64_t{1.1f64} };
    fmt::println( "{}", num1 );

    auto num2 { static_cast<long double>(1.2) };
    fmt::println( "{}", num2 );

    auto num3 { std::float128_t{1.3f128} };
    fmt::println( "{}", num3 );  // compile-time error
}
```

This is also the case with `std::float16_t`.

Why are these two types not formatted by {fmt}? Is it because they are not implemented yet, or is a specific format specifier required? I checked the [documentation](https://fmt.dev/latest/syntax.html) but could not find anything related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that **{fmt}** doesn't provide any formatters for extended floating point types itself. Attempting to format `std::float128_t` will result in an ambiguous overload on some level, because it is convertible to:

- `int`
- `long`
- ...

libstdc++ doesn't implement `operator<<(std::float128_t)`, and it may not be required. If the rank of `std::float128_t` is greater than `long double`, it may not be supported.

> - If the rank is less than or equal to that of `double`, inserts `static_cast<double>(value)` as in (6).
> - Otherwise, if the rank is less than or equal to that of long double, inserts `static_cast<long double>(value)` as in (7).
> - **Otherwise, an invocation of this overload is conditionally supported with implementation-defined semantics.**

- See [`std::ostream::operator<<`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt)

This means that we also can't rely on `#include <fmt/ostream.h>` as a fallback option.

In the meantime, you can use the **{fmt}** features that have been migrated to the standard:

```cpp
#include <stdfloat>
#include <format>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    auto num1 { std::float64_t{1.1f64} };
    std::cout << std::format( "{}\n", num1 );

    auto num2 { static_cast<long double>(1.2) };
    std::cout << std::format( "{}\n", num2 );

    auto num3 { std::float128_t{1.3f128} };
    std::cout << std::format( "{}\n", num3 );

    // or using {fmt} + <format>
    fmt::println( "{}", std::format( "{}", num3 ) );
    
    // or using {fmt} + GCC's __float128
    fmt::println( "{}", fmt::to_string( __float128{num3} ) );
}
```

*Note: eventually, we will be able to write `std::println`, but libstdc++ doesn't implement `<print>` yet*

---

See also: [C++ compiler support](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support)

Comment: "*For some reason, libstdc++ implements a formatter for std::uint128_t*" how is `std::uint128_t` in the standard library? I've never seen it before.

Comment: @digito_evo that was a mistake, I meant `std::float128_t`

Comment: `operator<<` has the problem that if `float128_t` is wider than `long double`, the standard has no usable `num_put` support. Then what?

Comment: @BoP *" Otherwise, an invocation of this overload is conditionally supported with implementation-defined semantics."*, I suppose that means we're out of luck when trying to `<< std::float128_t`

Comment: I edited the answer and added an alternative to using iostreams (and instead, relying on {fmt} + <format>).

Comment: Also, is it mentioned in the standard that fixed width floating point types are supported by <format>?

Comment: @digito_evo yes, the formatter for floating point types is implemented in terms of `std::to_chars` and `std::to_chars` is required to work with all floating point types. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/to_chars